# ambiguous overload in big numbers class

Tags: c++, class, casting, type-conversion

I am building a big number class and I am facing a problem that I can't solve on my own.

First of all, the class looks like this:

```
class bigNumber{
private:
    char v[BNmaxLength];
    int L;
    void setll(long long int);
    int comp(bigNumber);
    void erase0();
    void mult10(int);
    void div10(int);
public:
    bigNumber(){
        setll(0);
    }
    bigNumber(long long int q){
        setll(q);
    }
    bigNumber operator=(long long int);
    operator int();
    bool operator==(bigNumber);
    bool operator!=(bigNumber);
    bool operator<(bigNumber);
    bool operator<=(bigNumber);
    bool operator>(bigNumber);
    bool operator>=(bigNumber);
    bigNumber operator+(bigNumber);
    bigNumber operator+=(bigNumber);
    bigNumber& operator++();
    bigNumber operator++(int);
    bigNumber operator-(bigNumber);
    bigNumber operator-=(bigNumber);
    bigNumber& operator--();
    bigNumber operator--(int);
    bigNumber operator*(long long int);
    bigNumber operator*=(long long int);
    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream&, bigNumber&);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, bigNumber);
};
```

And I wanted to be able to write something like this:

```
bigNumber b=276743;
int a;
a=b;
```

so I overloaded the typecasting operator from bigNumber to int by doing so:

```
bigNumber::operator int(){
    int a=0;
    for(int i=L;i>=1;--i){
        a*=10;
        a+=v[i];
    }
    return a;
};
```

but then if I type

```
bigNumber b=276743;
int a=34672;
cout<<(b<a);
```

it displays this error:

> ambiguous overload for 'operator<' (operand types are 'bigNumber' and 'int')
>
> note: candidates are:
>
> note: operator<(int, int)
>
> note: bool bigNumber::operator<(bigNumber)

How can I typecast the bigNumber class in order to:

1. not get this error anymore
2. not use explicit type casting
3. always convert the int to bigNumber in order to not lose precision (I observe that it's not doing this when I write `a<b`)

Comment: *How can I typecast the bigNumber class* -- I suggest not to do this.  Even if you got your code to compile, do you know when and where your operator int() will be called?    Instead, just create a `to_int()` function.

Comment: Because I want them to be used just like an int or long long .

Comment: Seriously, if you wrote a non-toy program using your class, I bet you will see that `operator int()` would barely be used anywhere.  And in the cases where you do need to use it, just create a `to_int()` function, as previously stated.  The code would then compile, and the coder would explicitly see what is going on, instead of secret calls to int() being invoked.

Comment: `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, bigNumber);`  Also, the second parameter should be a `const bigNumber&`, not a value-type.

Answer (score 0):

First, possibly lossy operations should be explicit.

Second, have 3 overloads:

```
friend bool operator==(bignumber const&,bignumber const&);
friend bool operator==(int,bignumber const&);
friend bool operator==(bignumber const&,int);
```